# ¿Cómo eliminar tr clonado dinámicamente usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
  $(document).ready( function(){

    tabla = $('#tabla_sel');
    tr = $('tr:first', tabla);
    $('#addF').on('click', function (){
        tr.clone().appendTo(tabla).find(':text').val('');
    });

    $(".eliminarFila").on('click', function (){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });    
});
```

**TABLA HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="" class="add_btn" id="addF">
<input type="button" value="" class="eliminarFila">
    <table>
        <tbody id="tabla_sel" style="padding: 5px">
            <tr>
             <td>Fila</td>  
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Este código lo utilizo para clonar de una tabla tantos **`<tr>`** como necesite, pero al momento de querer borrar cada **`<tr>`** creado, no me realiza ninguna función.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código HTML? Pregunto para saber que elemento tiene el evento de `on('click'...)` con la clase `.eliminarFila` y saber si estás realizando la lógica correctamente

Comment: Hola @Lixus , edite la pregunta con los datos que me mencionas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imaginemos que tu tabla es esta:

```
<table id="tabla">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td><button class="eliminarFila">Eliminar</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td><button class="eliminarFila">Eliminar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Basándome en tu JS:**

> **EDIT:** recuerda que los elementos creados dinámicamente con JS deben ser llamados de la siguiente forma:
>   **`$(document).on("evento","selector",function(){});`**

```
$(document).on('click','.eliminarFila',function(){
    $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
});
```

La función **`closset`** de jQuery devuelve el primer antecesor de **`<span>`** que está dentro de un elemento **`<ul>`**, lo cual no te funciona.

> Por esa razón tienes que seleccionar **el padre del padre** del botón con clase
>   **eliminarFila**.

NOTA: solamente usé el botón **.eliminarFila** ya que es con el que tenías problema.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Buenísimo gracias me funciono a la perfeccion.

Comment: @AlexanderQuiroz me alegro de que te haya funcionado!

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu código **jQuery**, en la función para eliminar haces referencia al elemento **this** pero este corresponde al **input** con la clase **eliminarFila** y lo correcto es apuntar a la **tabla**, ademas en la funcion para Adicionar filas hace referencia a **.val()** siendo lo correcto buscar el tag **'td'** y luego eliminar su contenido con **.html()**, prueba con el siguiente ejemplo y te funcionara:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
 tabla = $('#tabla_sel');
 tr = $('tr:first', tabla);
 $('#addF').on('click', function (){
  tr.clone().appendTo(tabla).find('td').html('add');
 });

 $(".eliminarFila").on('click', function (){
  $('#tabla_sel tr:last').remove();
 });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Append" class="add_btn" id="addF">
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="eliminarFila">
<table>
 <tbody id="tabla_sel" style="padding: 5px">
  <tr>
   <td>Fila</td>  
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```